# C# momentary program pause

Tags: c#

Im trying to create a simple program of a stick man waving in the console using arrays in c#.
I have all of the symbols in the console but im having trouble with making his arm "Wave". I believe my main problem is needing the program to pause for a few seconds before the arm moves.
So, can anyone inform me on how to add in a pause in the program? Im pretty new to c# so im kind of a noob.

Thanks

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(milisseconds)`?

Comment: Please research your question before you ask.  Google "c# pause program" and you'll find a lot of relevant hits, several of them already asked here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Look into some of the [System.Threading namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading(v=vs.110).aspx), particularly the [Thread.Sleep method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides the exact "wait a set duration" functionality you're mentioning. Since you're dealing with fixed time animations, you may also want to consider the [Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to set up a "fire event at fixed intervals" functionality.